# Converter um Select com 2 option em HTML para 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, manipulador-de-evento

**Contexto:**

> Diariamente acesso um site diversas vezes durante o dia, do qual antes de efetivamente entrar, além de informar usuário e senha, tenho que selecionar o tipo de acesso entre os 2 existentes, acho ruim ter que ficar selecionando e depois clicar em entrar.

Código:

```html
    <select>
       <option value="A">Administrador</option>
       <option value="U">Usuário</option>
    </select>
    
    <br><br>
    <!-- Login -->

    <input name="login" type="submit" value="LOGIN">
```

Necessidade:

> Gostaria de modificar, se possível, esse login para 2 botões, um
>   **Administrador**, outro **Usuário**, e assim efetuar o login 
>   automaticamente.

Sei que é possível fazer isso via Extensões de navegadores, como o Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey, manipulando os elementos via JS, mas especificamente essa modificação não sei.

Alguém poderia me ajudar, ou dar alguma ideia?

---

**Detalhe adicional**:
Não tenho acesso ao código fonte, ou seja, não posso modificar, apenas manipular via browser.

Comment: Vou fornecer uma sugestão, mas é critério de cada um: No primeiro login, você deixa ele selecionar de qual forma entrar, após, adicione um cookie e toda vez que ele entrar, ele logará com aquela opção selecionada, e vocÊ exibirá na tela algo como: Você entrará como "Usuário" (clique aqui para alterar)... Algo desse gênero, então se o cara quer alterar o tipo de login, ele só clica nesse link, você exibe o dropdown e ele altera o tipo de login.

Comment: Porque você não valida o nível após o login? Não seria mais fácil? Aqui tenho uma situação semelhante, tenho 3 niveis de acesso, verifico o nível e depois carrego a página referente ao nível do usuário.

Comment: Adicionei um detalhe essencial na pergunte: Não tenho acesso ao código fonte, ou seja, não posso modificar, apenas manipular via browser. Obrigado Diego e Rafael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que consegui fazer foi isso, resolvendo meu problema, mesmo que não seja da melhor forma, por que os 2 botões ficaram abaixo do login, mas tudo bem.

```js
function addElement(parentTag, elementTag, html) {
    // Adds an element to the document
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName(parentTag)[0];
    var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
    newElement.innerHTML = html;
    p.appendChild(newElement);
};

function removeQuery(query) {
    // Removes an element from the document
    var element = document.querySelector(query);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

function addButton(elementName,value) {

  
    var html = '<button style="top: 0;" type="button" value="'+value+'" /> '+elementName+'</button>';
    addElement('body', 'div', html);
}

removeQuery('select');
addButton('Administrador','A');
addButton('Usuário','U');
```

```html
<select>
 <option value="A">Administrador</option>
 <option value="U">Usuário</option>
</select>
    
<br><br>
<!-- Login -->

<input name="login" type="submit" value="LOGIN"><br><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bem, espero ainda poder ajudar.

com jQuery:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".btn").click(function(){
                    $("#tipoLogin").val($(this).attr("name"));
                    $( "#formLogin" ).submit(); 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formLogin">
            <select name="tipoLogin" id="tipoLogin">
               <option value="A">Administrador</option>
               <option value="U">Usuário</option>
            </select>

            <br><br>
            <!-- Login -->

            <input type="text" name="user" />
            <input type="text" name="pass" />

            <br><br>

            <input class="btn" name="A" type="button" value="LOGIN with Administrator">
            <input class="btn" name="U" type="button" value="LOGIN with User">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Caso ajude, não esqueça de avaliar.

Comment: `+1` Entendi como fez, porém não posso modificar o HTML da página, teria que ser somente com manipulação do DOM da página :/ .. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar condições diferentes via GET.

Exemplo: login.php?t=A

No form, pegue este A e coloque num hidden field, desta maneira, o usuário não precisa ficar preenchendo o select toda vez que entra.

Acredito ser a forma mais simples. Existem outras, claro.

Comment: Então @Maykel, adicionei um detalhe essencial na pergunte: Não tenho acesso ao código fonte, ou seja, não posso modificar, apenas manipular via browser. Se eu tivesse, aaa se tivesse kkk vlw

Answer (score 1):

Eu tenho esse exemplo com sessão em javascript que abre um modal no qual utilizo a biblioteca do [**fancybox**](http://fancybox.net/) e [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/):

1. só precisa criar a imagem da empresa: `/img/logo_empresa.png`
2. div de overlay com a classe: `.layer_overlay`
3. A div onde vai aparecer o botão de sair: `<div id="session_login"></div>`

E colocar esse script na HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.layer_overlay').hide();
    if (!$.prototype.fancybox) {
        $('<script></script>', {
            type: 'text/javascript',
            src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js'
        }).appendTo('head');
        $('<link/>', {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            type: 'text/css',
            href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css'
        }).appendTo('head');
    }

    var modalLogin = {

            pagina_atual:'index',
            pg_adm:'administrador',
            pg_user:'usuario',

            tiposLogin : {
                A:'Administrador',
                U:'Usuário'
            },

            viewModal : function() {

                var content = '<div id="hello" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 login-box">\
                         <img src="/img/logo_empresa.png" border="0" class="text-center responsive-image">\
                         <h1 class="page-heading">Selecione o tipo de acesso:</h1>\
                             <ul class="acessos">\
                               <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="A" data-adm="'+modalLogin.tiposLogin.A+'" class="session_select">Administrador</a></li>\
                               <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="U" data-adm="'+modalLogin.tiposLogin.U+'" class="session_select">Usuário</a></li>\
                             </ul>\
                      </div>';
                        $.fancybox.open([
                            {
                                type: 'inline',
                                autoScale: true,
                                minHeight: 30,
                                content: content,
                                closeBtn:false
                            }
                        ], {
                            padding: 0
                        });
                         $('.layer_overlay').show();
            },
            mySession : function() {
                return localStorage.getItem('login')
            },
            setSession : function(login) {
                if (login == null) {
                    localStorage.setItem('login', null);
                    localStorage.removeItem('login');
                    localStorage.clear();
                } else {
                    localStorage.setItem('login', login);
                    $('#session_login').html('<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="reset_session">Sair ('+localStorage.getItem('login')+')</a>')
                }
            },
            closeModal : function() {
                $('.fancybox-wrap').remove();
                $('.layer_overlay').fadeOut('slow');
            }
        }


    $(document).on('click','#reset_session', function() {
        $('#session_login').html('');
        modalLogin.setSession(null);
        window.location.reload();
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem('login') == 'null' || localStorage.getItem('login') == null || localStorage.getItem('login') == undefined || !localStorage.getItem('login')) {
            if (!!$.prototype.fancybox) {
                modalLogin.viewModal();
                $(document).on('click','.session_select', function() {
                    var login = $(this).data('login');
                      modalLogin.setSession(login);
                    if (login == modalLogin.tiposLogin.A) {
                        window.location.href=modalLogin.pg_adm;
                    } else if (login == modalLogin.tiposLogin.U) {
                        window.location.href=modalLogin.pg_user;
                    } else {
                        modalLogin.closeModal();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            $('#session_login').html('<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="reset_session">Sair (Olá '+localStorage.getItem('adm')+'!)</a>')
        }
});
```

Comment: Vou testar amanhã, e falo, mas pelo código gostei!

Comment: `+1`Então Ivan, não posso adicionar nenhuma tag ou classe dentro do HTML, teria que fazer a alteração do DOM :/, mesmo assim Obrigado.